# ALB default rule best practices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an Application Load Balancer (ALB) that has many rules. Each rule directs traffic to distinct target groups, which represent different applications.

However, I noticed that the ALB can be accessed via its IP address (Even google bot), and it sends the traffic to the default rule, which directs it to one of the applications.

What is the best way / best practices to prevent this?

One idea I had to solve this issue is to return a 403 error code if the incoming request's host header doesn't match any of the applications. This approach would prevent the ALB from sending the traffic to the default rule.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 4XX as the default sounds fine for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what is behind the default target group.

What I have done in the past is configure the web server to use name-based virtual hosts & have the default simply return a 403 for any requests.

That way, traffic that includes a host header will be handled properly, but traffic that hits the IP address will always return a 403.